# How can I send file to api that use multer in node js?

Tags: node.js, request, multer, form-data

I want to send a file from a server to another server, using two apis, one that upload to the final server and one that read a form data and send it to an api that call the first api

**Upload to final server**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        mkdirp(configServer.dataDir+ "/tmp", function(err){
            console.log("err * : ", err)
            if(err)
                res.json({success:false, error:err})
            cb(null, configServer.dataDir+ "/tmp/")
        })
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("file**", file)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

exports.upload_in_server = function (req, res) {

    upload(req, res, function (err) {

         console.log("body : ", req.body)
         console.log("file : ", req.file)

        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            console.log("err 1 : ", err)
        } else if (err) {
            // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
            console.log("err 2 : ", err)
        }

         res.json({success: true})

    })

}

router.post("/myurl/uploadInServer",  UserController.upload_in_server);
```

In next, the api called to send the file to the final server

```
var storage2 = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        mkdirp(config.dataDir+ "/tmp", function(err){
            console.log("err * : ", err)
            if(err)
                res.json({success:false, error:err})
            cb(null, config.dataDir+ "/tmp/")
        })
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        console.log("file**", file)
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var upload2 = multer({ storage: storage2 }).single('file');

exports.user_coffre_fort_create_file2 = function (req, res) {

var querystring = require('querystring');

    upload2(req, res, function (err) {

        if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
            console.log("err 1 : ", err)
        } else if (err) {
            // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
            console.log("err 2 : ", err)
        }

        var FormData = require('form-data');

        var form = new FormData();

        const encoded = req.file.toString('base64')

        form.append('file', encoded);

        form.append('Name', "Lagaf");
        form.append('Surname', "Vincent");
        form.append('birthdate', "13/01/1960");

        request({
            url: "/myurl/uploadInServer",
            method: 'POST',
            json: querystring.stringify(form),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization": my_tokentoken}
            //
        }, function (err, stdout, body) {
            res.json({success:true})
        })
    })
}
```

This is what I receive in server, the body is not correct, and the file is undefined

```
body :  { '"_overheadLength': '420',
  _valueLength: '37',


writable: 'false',
  readable: 'true',
  dataSize: '0',
  maxDataSize: '2097152',
  pauseStreams: 'true',
  _released: 'false',
  _streams: 
   [ '----------------------------081543624686364985445462\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"\r\n\r\n',
     '[object Object]',
     '',
     '----------------------------081543624686364985445462\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Name"\r\n\r\n',
     'Lagaf',
     '',
     '----------------------------081543624686364985445462\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="Surname"\r\n\r\n',
     'Vincent',
     '',
     '----------------------------081543624686364985445462\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="birthdate"\r\n\r\n',
     '13/01/1960',
     '' ],
  _currentStream: '',
  _boundary: '--------------------------081543624686364985445462"' }
files :  undefined
```

How to have a correct body and 'req.file' that is not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you converting binary file to a base64-encoded string? And why `urlencoded` is used instead of `multipart/form-data`?

Try:

```
request({
    url: "/myurl/uploadInServer",
    method: 'POST',
    formData : {
        file: req.file,
        'Name': 'Lagaf',
        'Surname': 'Vincent',
        'birthdate': '13/01/1960'
    },
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        "Authorization": my_tokentoken
    }
}, function (err, stdout, body) {
    res.json({success:true})
})
```

Comment: I tried this before,
this is the error :
/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33
  source.on('error', function() {});
         ^

TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append

Comment: Hmmm... you need to convert `req.file` to stream or buffer. Try `req.file.buffer`

Comment: Thanks for your responses, 
with req.file.buffer, i have this error : 
/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:226
  } else if (options.filename || value.name || value.path) {
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at FormData._getContentDisposition (/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:226:40)
    at FormData._multiPartHeader (/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:177:33)
    at FormData.append (/sr_to_my_projectapi/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:70

Comment: I tried this : 
formData: querystring.stringify(obj),
this is what return the req.body :
body :  { '0': 'c',
  '1': 'f',
  '2': '_',
  '3': 'u',
  '4': 's',
  '5': 'e',
  '6': 'r',
  '7': '_',
  '8': 'i',
  '9': 'd',
  '10': '=',
  '11': '5',
  '12': 'c',
  '13': '2',
  '14': 'c',
  '15': 'd',
  '16': 'f',
  '17': '9',
  '18': 'f',
  '19': 'c',
  '20': 'b',
  '21': 'e',
  '22': 'e',
  '23': '2',
  '24': '7',
  '25': '4',

Comment: Regarding the previous issue `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` - it happens when one of the `formData` fields is `null` or `undefined`, please check it.

Comment: it's the req.file.buffer that is null